# Piping two files from an outside file (or a control file) in C unix

Tags: c, linux, pipe, exec

Hi i am having trouble wrapping my head around this concept.

I need to execute two files lets say a.c & b.c from a control file called control.c

I want to pipe the output of a.c to the input of b.c

I understand that file descriptors(fd):
fd 0 = stdin
fd 1 = stdout

I understand that creating a pipe requires an array of integers (two fds)

```
e.g.
zpipe[2]
pipe(zpipe)
```

i want to execute the files a and b and pipe the output of a to the input of b.

however i am confused at the concept as opening or reading said files would create a new fd. I understand the fd of a (e.g fda) can be set to 0 by calling fda = dup2 (fd,0). Would this not break the pipe as 0 is now closed?

if i called

```
execvp("a.c", args)
execvp("b.c", args)
```

how would i ensure these files are correctly piped and waited for?

Comment: Your nomenclature is confusing (to us), or shows you are confused.  Usually, `a.c` is a C source file — and it would be compiled into a standalone program `a` (or perhaps `a.exe`).  You run programs, or execute them.  It would be unusual (not impossible, but definitely unusual) to have an executable program named `a.c`.  Ditto for `b.c` and `b`.  You might call `if (dup2(zpipe[0], 0) != 0) { …handle error… }`, or `if (dup2(zpipe[1], 1) != 0) { …handle error… }`.

Comment: You have to decide whether `control` creates the pipe and forks twice, once to run `a` and once to run `b`, or whether `control` replaces itself with one of `a` or `b`, or whether `control` forks and the child creates the pipe and then forks and the grandchild runs one process (it could be `a` or `b`) while the child runs the other and `control` waits for its child to finish.  All are possible; in the absence of other information, it is not clear that there is a 'best' solution.  If `control` needs to do more, then the single-fork solution won't be appropriate.

Comment: Hi Jonathan a.c was used purely as an example name, it could of been ex1.c & ex2.c or whatever. The aim of what im trying to do is get inputs from a.c (or ex1.c as the case may be) and send them to b.c for processing and output. However after further research i have noted the best practice is "creates the pipe and forks twice" method, but im still struggling to understand how control holds the pipe flow from a -> b

Comment: And my comments apply equally to `ex1.c` and `ex2.c` or whatever, _mutatis mutandis_.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably want to use a pipe and fork to get the desired results. Take a look at the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369286/c-passing-a-pipe-thru-execve).

Comment: This really isn't an answer — it should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. i was attempting to run execvp with user defined programs. where i called execvp("a.c, args)

I should of been calling

execvp("./a", args)

Rookie mistake my apologies